# Gstreamer fail to play avi video-

Tags: video, gstreamer

I want to use Gstreamer to play video with the following command. By the way, there is no audio information in the source FlickAnimation.avi.

```
gst-launch filesrc location=FlickAnimation.avi !avidemux name=demux demux.video_00 ! queue ! ffdec_mpeg4   !ffmpegcolorspace !playsink
```

BUt it failed, here is the error info,

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAviDemux:demux: Internal data stream     error.
Additional debug info:
gstavidemux.c(5212): gst_avi_demux_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAviDemux:demux:
streaming stopped, reason not-linked
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Then I use the Gstreamer debug, and the infor are as follows,

```
gst-launch --gst-debug-level=3 !filesrc location=FlickAnimation.avi !avidemux 


0:00:00.001558790   598  0x11e4008 INFO                GST_INIT     gstquery.c:107:_gst_query_initialize: init queries
0:00:00.009293535   598  0x11e4008 INFO                GST_INIT gstmessage.c:73:_gst_message_initialize: init messages
0:00:00.010303629   598  0x11e4008 INFO      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:350:_gst_plugin_initialize: registering 0 static plugins
0:00:00.012185007   598  0x11e4008 INFO      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:255:gst_plugin_register_static: registered static plugin "staticelements"
0:00:00.012481987   598  0x11e4008 INFO      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:257:gst_plugin_register_static: added static plugin "staticelements", result: 1
0:00:00.013571080   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_REGISTRY gstregistry.c:1648:ensure_current_registry: reading registry cache: /root/.gstreamer-0.10/registry.arm.bin
0:00:00.124909893   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_REGISTRY gstregistrybinary.c:614:gst_registry_binary_read_cache: loaded /root/.gstreamer-0.10/registry.arm.bin in 0.110985 seconds
0:00:00.125468355   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_REGISTRY gstregistry.c:1518:scan_and_update_registry: Validating plugins from registry cache: /root/.gstreamer-0.10/registry.arm.bin
0:00:00.136105174   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_REGISTRY gstregistry.c:1610:scan_and_update_registry: Registry cache has not changed
0:00:00.136400760   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_REGISTRY gstregistry.c:1683:ensure_current_registry: registry reading and updating done, result = 1
0:00:00.136654364   598  0x11e4008 INFO                GST_INIT gst.c:805:init_post: GLib runtime version: 2.30.3
0:00:00.136933696   598  0x11e4008 INFO                GST_INIT gst.c:807:init_post: GLib headers version: 2.30.3
0:00:00.137347040   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_PIPELINE gstparse.c:334:gst_parse_launch_full: parsing pipeline description '!filesrc location=FlickAnimation.avi !avidemux name=demux demux.video_00 ! queue ! ffdec_mpeg4 !ffmpegcolorspace !playsink '
0:00:00.183772341   598  0x11e4008 INFO      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:859:gst_plugin_load_file: plugin "/usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstcoreelements.so" loaded
0:00:00.184138701   598  0x11e4008 INFO     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:376:gst_element_factory_create: creating element "filesrc"
0:00:00.185647227   598  0x11e4008 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:728:gst_element_add_pad:<GstBaseSrc@0x1272000> adding pad 'src'
0:00:00.186236055   598  0x11e4008 INFO                 filesrc gstfilesrc.c:374:gst_file_src_set_location: filename : FlickAnimation.avi
0:00:00.186512309   598  0x11e4008 INFO                 filesrc gstfilesrc.c:375:gst_file_src_set_location: uri      : file:///pos_demo/video/FlickAnimation.avi
0:00:00.259798194   598  0x11e4008 INFO      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:859:gst_plugin_load_file: plugin "/usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstavi.so" loaded
0:00:00.260089584   598  0x11e4008 INFO     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:376:gst_element_factory_create: creating element "avidemux"
0:00:00.268652741   598  0x11e4008 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:728:gst_element_add_pad:<GstAviDemux@0x1282298> adding pad 'sink'
0:00:00.269410547   598  0x11e4008 INFO     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:376:gst_element_factory_create: creating element "queue"
0:00:00.270858485   598  0x11e4008 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:728:gst_element_add_pad:<GstQueue@0x1284080> adding pad 'sink'
0:00:00.271484935   598  0x11e4008 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:728:gst_element_add_pad:<GstQueue@0x1284080> adding pad 'src'
0:00:00.383902563   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_TYPEFIND gsttypefind.c:83:gst_type_find_register: registering typefind function for fftype_avs
0:00:00.384653295   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_TYPEFIND gsttypefind.c:83:gst_type_find_register: registering typefind function for fftype_daud
0:00:00.385330617   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_TYPEFIND gsttypefind.c:83:gst_type_find_register: registering typefind function for fftype_ea
0:00:00.385952639   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_TYPEFIND gsttypefind.c:83:gst_type_find_register: registering typefind function for fftype_ffm
0:00:00.386635737   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_TYPEFIND gsttypefind.c:83:gst_type_find_register: registering typefind function for fftype_4xm
0:00:00.387258279   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_TYPEFIND gsttypefind.c:83:gst_type_find_register: registering typefind function for fftype_gxf
0:00:00.387892749   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_TYPEFIND gsttypefind.c:83:gst_type_find_register: registering typefind function for fftype_idcin
0:00:00.388501919   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_TYPEFIND gsttypefind.c:83:gst_type_find_register: registering typefind function for fftype_ipmovie
0:00:00.389184857   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_TYPEFIND gsttypefind.c:83:gst_type_find_register: registering typefind function for fftype_mm
0:00:00.389816667   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_TYPEFIND gsttypefind.c:83:gst_type_find_register: registering typefind function for fftype_mmf
0:00:00.390735371   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_TYPEFIND gsttypefind.c:83:gst_type_find_register: registering typefind function for fftype_nsv
0:00:00.391378727   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_TYPEFIND gsttypefind.c:83:gst_type_find_register: registering typefind function for fftype_nut
0:00:00.392173103   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_TYPEFIND gsttypefind.c:83:gst_type_find_register: registering typefind function for fftype_RoQ
0:00:00.392852209   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_TYPEFIND gsttypefind.c:83:gst_type_find_register: registering typefind function for fftype_film_cpk
0:00:00.393555368   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_TYPEFIND gsttypefind.c:83:gst_type_find_register: registering typefind function for fftype_smk
0:00:00.394246352   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_TYPEFIND gsttypefind.c:83:gst_type_find_register: registering typefind function for fftype_sol
0:00:00.394905460   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_TYPEFIND gsttypefind.c:83:gst_type_find_register: registering typefind function for fftype_psxstr
0:00:00.395748130   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_TYPEFIND gsttypefind.c:83:gst_type_find_register: registering typefind function for fftype_vmd
0:00:00.396487456   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_TYPEFIND gsttypefind.c:83:gst_type_find_register: registering typefind function for fftype_wc3movie
0:00:00.397108598   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_TYPEFIND gsttypefind.c:83:gst_type_find_register: registering typefind function for fftype_wsaud
0:00:00.728328134   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_TYPEFIND gsttypefind.c:83:gst_type_find_register: registering typefind function for fftype_wsvqa
0:00:00.728991314   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_TYPEFIND gsttypefind.c:83:gst_type_find_register: registering typefind function for fftype_yuv4mpegpipe
0:00:00.734212168   598  0x11e4008 INFO      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:859:gst_plugin_load_file: plugin "/usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstffmpeg.so" loaded
0:00:00.734503370   598  0x11e4008 INFO     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:376:gst_element_factory_create: creating element "ffdec_mpeg4"
0:00:00.736008414   598  0x11e4008 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:728:gst_element_add_pad:<ffdec_mpeg4@0x129c358> adding pad 'sink'
0:00:00.736558490   598  0x11e4008 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:728:gst_element_add_pad:<ffdec_mpeg4@0x129c358> adding pad 'src'
0:00:00.777471444   598  0x11e4008 INFO      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:859:gst_plugin_load_file: plugin "/usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstffmpegcolorspace.so" loaded
0:00:00.777795742   598  0x11e4008 INFO     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:376:gst_element_factory_create: creating element "ffmpegcolorspace"
0:00:00.784120077   598  0x11e4008 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:728:gst_element_add_pad:<GstBaseTransform@0x12ac078> adding pad 'sink'
0:00:00.784654633   598  0x11e4008 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:728:gst_element_add_pad:<GstBaseTransform@0x12ac078> adding pad 'src'
0:00:00.833664552   598  0x11e4008 INFO      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:859:gst_plugin_load_file: plugin "/usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstplaybin.so" loaded
0:00:00.833959286   598  0x11e4008 INFO     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:376:gst_element_factory_create: creating element "playsink"
0:00:00.836653094   598  0x11e4008 ERROR           GST_PIPELINE ./grammar.y:862:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: link without source element
0:00:00.836982596   598  0x11e4008 INFO     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:376:gst_element_factory_create: creating element "pipeline"
0:00:00.838180042   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_PIPELINE ./grammar.y:568:gst_parse_perform_link: linking filesrc0:(any) to demux:(any) (0/0) with caps "(nil)"
0:00:00.838590184   598  0x11e4008 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1698:gst_element_link_pads_full: trying to link element filesrc0:(any) to element demux:(any)
0:00:00.838912830   598  0x11e4008 INFO                GST_PADS gstutils.c:1032:gst_pad_check_link: trying to link filesrc0:src and demux:sink
0:00:00.839262212   598  0x11e4008 INFO                GST_PADS gstutils.c:1596:prepare_link_maybe_ghosting: filesrc0 and demux in same bin, no need for ghost pads
0:00:00.839683184   598  0x11e4008 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:1978:gst_pad_link_prepare: trying to link filesrc0:src and demux:sink
0:00:00.840044478   598  0x11e4008 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2161:gst_pad_link_full: linked filesrc0:src and demux:sink, successful
0:00:00.840450532   598  0x11e4008 INFO           GST_PARENTAGE gstbin.c:3762:gst_bin_get_by_name: [pipeline0]: looking up child element demux
0:00:00.840771938   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_PIPELINE ./grammar.y:568:gst_parse_perform_link: linking demux:demux to queue0:(any) (1/0) with caps "(nil)"
0:00:00.841082304   598  0x11e4008 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1698:gst_element_link_pads_full: trying to link element demux:video_00 to element queue0:(any)
0:00:00.841390362   598  0x11e4008 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:972:gst_element_get_static_pad: no such pad 'video_00' in element "demux"
0:00:00.841664658   598  0x11e4008 INFO                 default gstutils.c:2037:gst_element_link_pads_filtered: Could not link pads: demux:video_00 - queue0:(null)
0:00:00.841987814   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_PIPELINE ./grammar.y:568:gst_parse_perform_link: linking queue0:(any) to ffdec_mpeg40:(any) (0/0) with caps "(nil)"
0:00:00.842302988   598  0x11e4008 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1698:gst_element_link_pads_full: trying to link element queue0:(any) to element ffdec_mpeg40:(any)
0:00:01.173214247   598  0x11e4008 INFO                GST_PADS gstutils.c:1032:gst_pad_check_link: trying to link queue0:src and ffdec_mpeg40:sink
0:00:01.173704507   598  0x11e4008 INFO                GST_PADS gstutils.c:1596:prepare_link_maybe_ghosting: queue0 and ffdec_mpeg40 in same bin, no need for ghost pads
0:00:01.174091201   598  0x11e4008 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:1978:gst_pad_link_prepare: trying to link queue0:src and ffdec_mpeg40:sink
0:00:01.174450731   598  0x11e4008 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2161:gst_pad_link_full: linked queue0:src and ffdec_mpeg40:sink, successful
0:00:01.174860127   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_PIPELINE ./grammar.y:568:gst_parse_perform_link: linking ffdec_mpeg40:(any) to ffmpegcsp0:(any) (0/0) with caps "(nil)"
0:00:01.175184191   598  0x11e4008 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1698:gst_element_link_pads_full: trying to link element ffdec_mpeg40:(any) to element ffmpegcsp0:(any)
0:00:01.175478117   598  0x11e4008 INFO                GST_PADS gstutils.c:1032:gst_pad_check_link: trying to link ffdec_mpeg40:src and ffmpegcsp0:sink
0:00:01.209021014   598  0x11e4008 INFO                GST_PADS gstutils.c:1596:prepare_link_maybe_ghosting: ffdec_mpeg40 and ffmpegcsp0 in same bin, no need for ghost pads
0:00:01.209427680   598  0x11e4008 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:1978:gst_pad_link_prepare: trying to link ffdec_mpeg40:src and ffmpegcsp0:sink
0:00:01.242462005   598  0x11e4008 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2161:gst_pad_link_full: linked ffdec_mpeg40:src and ffmpegcsp0:sink, successful
0:00:01.242912317   598  0x11e4008 INFO            GST_PIPELINE ./grammar.y:568:gst_parse_perform_link: linking ffmpegcsp0:(any) to playsink0:(any) (0/0) with caps "(nil)"
0:00:01.243237831   598  0x11e4008 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1698:gst_element_link_pads_full: trying to link element ffmpegcsp0:(any) to element playsink0:(any)
0:00:01.273302364   598  0x11e4008 INFO     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:374:gst_element_factory_create: creating element "tee" named "audiotee"
0:00:01.274630233   598  0x11e4008 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:728:gst_element_add_pad:<GstTee@0x12ba000> adding pad 'sink'
0:00:01.275024699   598  0x11e4008 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:975:gst_element_get_static_pad: found pad audiotee:sink
0:00:01.275450581   598  0x11e4008 INFO              GST_STATES gstelement.c:2435:gst_element_continue_state:<audiotee> committing state from NULL to READY, pending PAUSED, next PAUSED
0:00:01.275772761   598  0x11e4008 INFO              GST_STATES gstelement.c:2365:_priv_gst_element_state_changed:<audiotee> notifying about state-changed NULL to READY (PAUSED pending)
0:00:01.276194935   598  0x11e4008 INFO              GST_STATES gstelement.c:2442:gst_element_continue_state:<audiotee> continue state change READY to PAUSED, final PAUSED
0:00:01.276590041   598  0x11e4008 INFO              GST_STATES gstelement.c:2460:gst_element_continue_state:<audiotee> completed state change to PAUSED
0:00:01.276917951   598  0x11e4008 INFO              GST_STATES gstelement.c:2365:_priv_gst_element_state_changed:<audiotee> notifying about state-changed READY to PAUSED (VOID_PENDING pending)
0:00:01.278029391   598  0x11e4008 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:1978:gst_pad_link_prepare: trying to link audio_sink:proxypad0 and audiotee:sink
0:00:01.278387647   598  0x11e4008 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2161:gst_pad_link_full: linked audio_sink:proxypad0 and audiotee:sink, successful
0:00:01.278770135   598  0x11e4008 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:728:gst_element_add_pad:<playsink0> adding pad 'audio_sink'
0:00:01.279207105   598  0x11e4008 INFO                GST_PADS gstutils.c:1596:prepare_link_maybe_ghosting: ffmpegcsp0 and playsink0 in same bin, no need for ghost pads
0:00:01.611396842   598  0x11e4008 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:1978:gst_pad_link_prepare: trying to link ffmpegcsp0:src and playsink0:audio_sink
0:00:01.611822588   598  0x11e4008 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2161:gst_pad_link_full: linked ffmpegcsp0:src and playsink0:audio_sink, successful
```

WARNING: erroneous pipeline: link without source element
    #

Answer (score 1):

try this pipeline:

```
gst-launch filesrc location=FlickAnimation.avi ! decodebin ! ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink
```

Comment: Thank you martien9. But what's the difference between xvimagesink and playsink?

Comment: I am not sure but I think playsink is use to play any type of source.  xvimagesink is plugin to show only video. After it's not really different. Can you tell me if the pipeline, i send you work?

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't work by now, because I haven't plugined the xvimagesink element. I have to upgrade the Gstreamer first...