# gstreamer:No such element or plugin 'videotestsrc'

Tags: linux, gstreamer

I have upgrade my gstreamer to the lastest version 1.4.0 on Linux, including the gst-plugins-base/good/bad/ugly. But when I try to play a video, I cannot find many elements, such as xvimagesink, videotestsrc and autovideosink.
I want to know how can I add these elements?

```
gst-launch --gst-debug-level=3 !filesrc location=FlickAnimation.avi !avidemux name=demux demux.video_00 ! queue ! ffdec_mpeg4   !ffmpegcolorspace !autovideosink
```

Comment: what does this pipeline have to do with those elements? What pipelines are you trying where those elements are not found?

Comment: I've tried to play avi video with gstreamer. But it doesn't work somehow, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076242/gstreamer-fail-to-play-avi-video  Someone told me to try with other demux and decoder, then I found I cannot find many elements.

Answer (score 1):

Post the result of `gst-inspect` of the three plugins which you have mentioned.

Try to locate below three files, these are libraries for the mentioned plugins. Please change the folder name of gstreamer version according to what you have in your machine

Filename:     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/**libgstvideotestsrc.so**
  Filename:     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/**libgstxvimagesink.so**
  Filename:     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/**libgstautodetect.so**

A possible reason: You may have installed mulitple versions of `gstreamer`

*P.S.* xvimagesink generally works only when you have a graphics card or a harwdware for graphics

Comment: #    
# gst-inspect autovideosink  
No such element or plugin 'autovideosink'  
# gst-inspect videotestsrc  
No such element or plugin 'videotestsrc'  
# gst-inspect xvimagesink  
No such element or plugin 'xvimagesink';   I cannot find these .so files you mentioned in my dir. But I'm sure I have installed these four plugins, good/base/ugly/bad...  I just install the 1.4.0 version.

Comment: Remove them and install again !

Answer (score 1):

If you're using gstreamer 1.x you probably want to use gst-launch-1.0 and gst-inspect-1.0. It's just a guess, but maybe you installed gstreamer 1.x plugins but are using the tools from 0.10 that will look for 0.10 plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, you will find a solution following one of the steps provided in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61634481/11923286).

In my case, runnig `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib` made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Since most of these plugins and their names keep changing with the various versions, if not specifically required, I'd recommend using the 'autoaudiosink','autovideosink', .....'auto*src' etc.

Takes out most complications (beginner point of view)

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `gstreamer-1.0` cache, its usually found in `~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0` and run `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib` include all the paths, where the custom gstreamer lib files are stored.