# Gstreamer Error: pipeline could not be constructed: no element "v4l2src"

Tags: gstreamer, v4l2

Am using Ubuntu(14.04) and I am getting this error while trying to use gstreamer.

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src !  video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 !  x264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay !  udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

I have checked the gst-inspect-1.0 v4l2src

It say element not found "No such element or plugin 'v4l2src'"

What should I do ? From where can I get this element or plugin. I have tried resinstalling entire gstreamer. But am unable to do so.

Answer (score 14):

the `v4l2src` plugin belongs to the `gstreamer-plugins-good` package; so

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
```

should help you out

Gstreamer packages most of its plugins in separate packages; you have

- gst-plugins-base
- gst-plugins-good
- gst-plugins-ugly

and more. They are pluggable; so just updating gstreamer won't auto-select gst-plugins-good for you...

Comment: remove your cache (rm .cache/gstreamer-1.0), then run gst-inspect-1.0 v4l2src...?

Comment: it is difficult to debug this from a distance. what does gst-inspect-1.0 v4l2src tell you? I have ubuntu 14.04 as well and the package gstreamer1.0-plugins-good provides  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideo4linux2.so which provides v4l2src plugin

Comment: I edited my aswer to give you the exact command (I missed teh 1.0 in the package name...) hope this helps you out

Answer (score 10):

I had this same issue a while back, and what caused it for me was the fact that Anaconda was installed and had its base environment active. The solution was to run the command:

```
conda deactivate
```

And then try again.

Note: In my particular case it was harder to spot because I also had Oh-My-Bash installed and it removed Anaconda's environment indicator in the terminal.

Comment: thanks for this comment! This could have been a few hours of head scratching.

Answer (score 3):

Does

```
gst-inspect-1.0 -b
```

list any blacklisted plugins? If not check the the pluging pysically exists:

```
locate libgstvideo4linux2.so
```

There should be one under e.g.

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideo4linux2.so
```

or

```
/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideo4linux2.so
```

Then remove the registry cache again and run

```
GST_DEBUG="*:5" gst-inspect-1.0 2>debug.log
```

Search the log for v4l2 and check if gstreamer reports a reason why it won't load the plugin.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using a gstreamer-1.0 on Raspberry and I was having the same issue. As I was running out of options I've tried to install also the 0.10 plugins and unexpectedly it works.

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
```

my 2 cent ^_^

EDIT:
Well, actually it doen't work yet, but at least it's giving me a different error :)

EDIT 2:
It was a syntax error, It actually works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

My error was due to Anaconda virtual environment and other missing plug-in. I solved by [this][1]:
`conda deactivate`

`sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly libxml2 libpcap0.8 libaudit1 libnotify4`

Answer (score 0):

For my case the short answer is:

Run `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib`

Long answer:

Following the steps from @ensonic, I saw that most of my libraries were blacklisted.

1. Did `rm -rf ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/` to clean the cache
2. Did `gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src` and got many errors like this:

   `(gst-plugin-scanner:5082): GStreamer-WARNING **: 19:41:22.907: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstttmlsubs.so': librga.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Which showed that I didn't have the `librga.so` file

3. I could find `librga.so` on my system by running `locate librga.so`, but it seems that it was not on my dynamic shared libraries path. To do that I only had to run `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib`

Answer (score -1):

On Ubuntu you can install with just:

```
sudo apt-get install v4l-utils
```