# How to configure v4l2src for GStream?

Tags: linux, gstreamer, v4l2, gstreamer-1.0, v4l

I am trying stream a webcam stream to `.flv` format using GStreamer. Something similar to below command.

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! flvmux ! filesink location=xyz.flv
```

I am getting below error -

> erroneous pipeline: no element "v4l2src"

I goolgled around for this error, tried many options mentioned in below links. But it seem not working for Ubuntu 16.04 OS.

[Gstreamer Error: pipeline could not be constructed: no element "v4l2src"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712079/gstreamer-error-pipeline-could-not-be-constructed-no-element-v4l2src)

**update:** I used  gst-inspect-1.0 to get below output to see all the installed plugins.

```
app:  appsrc: AppSrc
app:  appsink: AppSink
videoconvert:  videoconvert: Colorspace converter
coreelements:  capsfilter: CapsFilter
coreelements:  concat: Concat
coreelements:  dataurisrc: data: URI source element
coreelements:  downloadbuffer: DownloadBuffer
coreelements:  fakesrc: Fake Source
coreelements:  fakesink: Fake Sink
coreelements:  fdsrc: Filedescriptor Source
coreelements:  fdsink: Filedescriptor Sink
coreelements:  filesrc: File Source
coreelements:  funnel: Funnel pipe fitting
coreelements:  identity: Identity
coreelements:  input-selector: Input selector
coreelements:  output-selector: Output selector
coreelements:  queue: Queue
coreelements:  queue2: Queue 2
coreelements:  filesink: File Sink
coreelements:  tee: Tee pipe fitting
coreelements:  typefind: TypeFind
coreelements:  multiqueue: MultiQueue
coreelements:  valve: Valve element
coreelements:  streamiddemux: Streamid Demux
audiotestsrc:  audiotestsrc: Audio test source
tcp:  socketsrc: socket source
tcp:  tcpclientsink: TCP client sink
tcp:  tcpclientsrc: TCP client source
tcp:  tcpserversink: TCP server sink
tcp:  tcpserversrc: TCP server source
tcp:  multifdsink: Multi filedescriptor sink
tcp:  multisocketsink: Multi socket sink
videoscale:  videoscale: Video scaler
audioconvert:  audioconvert: Audio converter
typefindfunctions: video/x-ms-asf: asf, wm, wma, wmv
typefindfunctions: audio/x-musepack: mpc, mpp, mp+
typefindfunctions: audio/x-au: au, snd
typefindfunctions: video/x-msvideo: avi
typefindfunctions: audio/qcelp: qcp
typefindfunctions: video/x-cdxa: dat
typefindfunctions: video/x-vcd: dat
typefindfunctions: audio/x-imelody: imy, ime, imelody
typefindfunctions: audio/midi: mid, midi
typefindfunctions: audio/riff-midi: mid, midi
typefindfunctions: audio/mobile-xmf: mxmf
typefindfunctions: video/x-fli: flc, fli
typefindfunctions: application/x-id3v2: mp3, mp2, mp1, mpga, ogg, flac, tta
typefindfunctions: application/x-id3v1: mp3, mp2, mp1, mpga, ogg, flac, tta
typefindfunctions: application/x-apetag: mp3, ape, mpc, wv
typefindfunctions: audio/x-ttafile: tta
typefindfunctions: audio/x-mod: 669, amf, ams, dbm, digi, dmf, dsm, gdm, far, imf, it, j2b, mdl, med, mod, mt2, mtm, okt, psm, ptm, sam, s3m, stm, stx, ult, umx, xm
typefindfunctions: audio/mpeg: mp3, mp2, mp1, mpga
typefindfunctions: audio/x-ac3: ac3, eac3
typefindfunctions: audio/x-dts: dts
typefindfunctions: audio/x-gsm: gsm
typefindfunctions: video/mpeg-sys: mpe, mpeg, mpg
typefindfunctions: video/mpegts: ts, mts
typefindfunctions: application/ogg: ogg, oga, ogv, ogm, ogx, spx, anx, axa, axv
typefindfunctions: video/mpeg-elementary: mpv, mpeg, mpg
typefindfunctions: video/mpeg4: m4v
typefindfunctions: video/x-h263: h263, 263
typefindfunctions: video/x-h264: h264, x264, 264
typefindfunctions: video/x-h265: h265, x265, 265
typefindfunctions: video/x-nuv: nuv
typefindfunctions: audio/x-m4a: m4a
typefindfunctions: application/x-3gp: 3gp
typefindfunctions: video/quicktime: mov, mp4
typefindfunctions: image/x-quicktime: qif, qtif, qti
typefindfunctions: image/jp2: jp2
typefindfunctions: video/mj2: mj2
typefindfunctions: text/html: htm, html
typefindfunctions: application/vnd.rn-realmedia: ra, ram, rm, rmvb
typefindfunctions: application/x-pn-realaudio: ra, ram, rm, rmvb
typefindfunctions: application/x-shockwave-flash: swf, swfl
typefindfunctions: application/dash+xml: mpd, MPD
typefindfunctions: application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml: no extensions
typefindfunctions: video/x-flv: flv
typefindfunctions: text/plain: txt
typefindfunctions: text/utf-16: txt
typefindfunctions: text/utf-32: txt
typefindfunctions: text/uri-list: ram
typefindfunctions: application/itc: itc
typefindfunctions: application/x-hls: m3u8
typefindfunctions: application/sdp: sdp
typefindfunctions: application/smil: smil
typefindfunctions: application/ttml+xml: ttml+xml
typefindfunctions: application/xml: xml
typefindfunctions: audio/x-wav: wav
typefindfunctions: audio/x-aiff: aiff, aif, aifc
typefindfunctions: audio/x-svx: iff, svx
typefindfunctions: audio/x-paris: paf
typefindfunctions: audio/x-nist: nist
typefindfunctions: audio/x-voc: voc
typefindfunctions: audio/x-sds: sds
typefindfunctions: audio/x-ircam: sf
typefindfunctions: audio/x-w64: w64
typefindfunctions: audio/x-rf64: rf64
typefindfunctions: audio/x-shorten: shn
typefindfunctions: application/x-ape: ape
typefindfunctions: image/jpeg: jpg, jpe, jpeg
typefindfunctions: image/gif: gif
typefindfunctions: image/png: png
typefindfunctions: image/bmp: bmp
typefindfunctions: image/tiff: tif, tiff
typefindfunctions: image/webp: webp
typefindfunctions: image/x-exr: exr
typefindfunctions: image/x-portable-pixmap: pnm, ppm, pgm, pbm
typefindfunctions: video/x-matroska: mkv, mka, mk3d, webm
typefindfunctions: application/mxf: mxf
typefindfunctions: video/x-mve: mve
typefindfunctions: video/x-dv: dv, dif
typefindfunctions: audio/x-amr-nb-sh: amr
typefindfunctions: audio/x-amr-wb-sh: amr
typefindfunctions: audio/iLBC-sh: ilbc
typefindfunctions: audio/x-sbc: sbc
typefindfunctions: audio/x-sid: sid
typefindfunctions: image/x-xcf: xcf
typefindfunctions: video/x-mng: mng
typefindfunctions: image/x-jng: jng
typefindfunctions: image/x-xpixmap: xpm
typefindfunctions: image/x-sun-raster: ras
typefindfunctions: application/x-bzip: bz2
typefindfunctions: application/x-gzip: gz
typefindfunctions: application/zip: zip
typefindfunctions: application/x-compress: Z
typefindfunctions: subtitle/x-kate: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-subtitle-vtt: vtt
typefindfunctions: audio/x-flac: flac
typefindfunctions: audio/x-vorbis: no extensions
typefindfunctions: video/x-theora: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-ogm-video: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-ogm-audio: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-ogm-text: no extensions
typefindfunctions: audio/x-speex: no extensions
typefindfunctions: audio/x-celt: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-ogg-skeleton: no extensions
typefindfunctions: text/x-cmml: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-executable: no extensions
typefindfunctions: audio/aac: aac, adts, adif, loas
typefindfunctions: audio/x-spc: spc
typefindfunctions: audio/x-wavpack: wv, wvp
typefindfunctions: audio/x-wavpack-correction: wvc
typefindfunctions: audio/x-caf: caf
typefindfunctions: application/postscript: ps
typefindfunctions: image/svg+xml: svg
typefindfunctions: application/x-rar: rar
typefindfunctions: application/x-tar: tar
typefindfunctions: application/x-ar: a
typefindfunctions: application/x-ms-dos-executable: dll, exe, ocx, sys, scr, msstyles, cpl
typefindfunctions: video/x-dirac: no extensions
typefindfunctions: multipart/x-mixed-replace: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-mmsh: no extensions
typefindfunctions: video/vivo: viv
typefindfunctions: audio/x-nsf: nsf
typefindfunctions: audio/x-gym: gym
typefindfunctions: audio/x-ay: ay
typefindfunctions: audio/x-gbs: gbs
typefindfunctions: audio/x-vgm: vgm
typefindfunctions: audio/x-sap: sap
typefindfunctions: video/x-ivf: ivf
typefindfunctions: audio/x-kss: kss
typefindfunctions: application/pdf: pdf
typefindfunctions: application/msword: doc
typefindfunctions: image/vnd.adobe.photoshop: psd
typefindfunctions: image/vnd.wap.wbmp: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-yuv4mpeg: no extensions
typefindfunctions: image/x-icon: no extensions
typefindfunctions: image/x-degas: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/octet-stream: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-ssa: ssa, ass
typefindfunctions: video/x-pva: pva
typefindfunctions: audio/x-xi: xi
typefindfunctions: audio/audible: aa, aax
coretracers:  latency (GstTracerFactory)
coretracers:  log (GstTracerFactory)
coretracers:  rusage (GstTracerFactory)
coretracers:  stats (GstTracerFactory)
coretracers:  leaks (GstTracerFactory)
adder:  adder: Adder
encoding:  encodebin: Encoder Bin
playback:  playbin: Player Bin 2
playback:  playbin3: Player Bin 3
playback:  playsink: Player Sink
playback:  subtitleoverlay: Subtitle Overlay
playback:  streamsynchronizer: Stream Synchronizer
playback:  decodebin: Decoder Bin
playback:  decodebin3: Decoder Bin 3
playback:  uridecodebin: URI Decoder
playback:  urisourcebin: URI reader
playback:  parsebin: Parse Bin
rawparse:  unalignedaudioparse: unalignedaudioparse
rawparse:  unalignedvideoparse: unalignedvideoparse
rawparse:  rawaudioparse: rawaudioparse
rawparse:  rawvideoparse: rawvideoparse
volume:  volume: Volume
pbtypes:  GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet (GstDynamicTypeFactory)
subparse: subparse_typefind: srt, sub, mpsub, mdvd, smi, txt, dks, vtt
subparse:  subparse: Subtitle parser
subparse:  ssaparse: SSA Subtitle Parser
audioresample:  audioresample: Audio resampler
audiorate:  audiorate: Audio rate adjuster
videorate:  videorate: Video rate adjuster
gio:  giosink: GIO sink
gio:  giosrc: GIO source
gio:  giostreamsink: GIO stream sink
gio:  giostreamsrc: GIO stream source
videotestsrc:  videotestsrc: Video test source
staticelements:  bin: Generic bin
staticelements:  pipeline: Pipeline object

Total count: 22 plugins, 209 features
**
```

strong text**

Comment: Could you try listing your plugins using `gst-inspect-1.0`.

Comment: @AlperKucukkomurler - Updated the post. Hope it helps

Comment: I see that you don't have `v4l2src` installed. `v4l2src` is located in gst-plugins-good package. You can get it with `apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-good`.

But in the question you wrote that you wanted to stream a 'file' to .flv format. `v4l2src` captures from the camera. Are you sure that this is the pipe you want to use?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, that was error now corrected. I need webcam stream to flv or mp4.

Comment: @AlperKucukkomurler - when i tried that package to install, it says `gstreamer1.0-plugins-good is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4).`

Comment: Could it be that you have another installation (such as anaconda)? You can see which gstreamer you are running with `which gst-launch-1.0`.

Comment: @AlperKucukkomurler  Totally right! I have it from anaconda. So what should I do now ? any workaround without un-installing the anaconda ? Thank you

Comment: Yes, I have encountered the same problem. I found two ways to get around this. First way is to call gst-launch from the root folder such as `/usr/bin/gst-launch-1.0 <your-pipe>`. The other, more practical and also more risky way is to delete gst-launch-1.0 and gst-inspect-1.o binaries from /home/<your-user>/anaconda3/bin/ directory. If you find a better way please share it here.

Comment: Sure, will share it. Thank you