# gstreamer: No such element or plugin 'v4l2sink'

Tags: gstreamer

## The problem

I am trying to execute a script. Part of it needs to execute v4l2sink. I tried to execute this

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1 & mplayer -tv device=/dev/video1 tv://
```

to check part of the code and it fails. The problem is the first part, meaning:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1
```

I get

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "v4l2sink"
```

This line should work as it is referenced in the [documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-v4l2sink.html). The following line does not work either and I think the root of the problem is the same.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! navigationtest ! v4l2sink

WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "navigationtest"
```

That line has been taken from the same part of the [documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-v4l2sink.html).

## What I have tried

I checked that /dev/video1 existed and it does. It was created with

```
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback video_nr=1,10 card_label="mobile_cam","OBS Cam" exclusive_caps=1
```

Which I took and adapted from the [v4l2loopback documentation](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback#options).

I have check if the module has been blacklisted following other similar questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712079/gstreamer-error-pipeline-could-not-be-constructed-no-element-v4l2src/61634481#61634481). It is not blacklisted:

```
Blacklisted files:

Total count: 0 blacklisted files
```

Although it is not blacklisted it cannot be found:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 v4l2sink

No such element or plugin 'v4l2sink'
```

The whole list of plugins and features is the following:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 

videotestsrc:  videotestsrc: Video test source
pbtypes:  GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet (GstDynamicTypeFactory)
coretracers:  latency (GstTracerFactory)
coretracers:  log (GstTracerFactory)
coretracers:  rusage (GstTracerFactory)
coretracers:  stats (GstTracerFactory)
coretracers:  leaks (GstTracerFactory)
adder:  adder: Adder
audiomixer:  audiomixer: AudioMixer
audiomixer:  liveadder: AudioMixer
audiomixer:  audiointerleave: AudioInterleave
videoconvert:  videoconvert: Colorspace converter
coreelements:  capsfilter: CapsFilter
coreelements:  concat: Concat
coreelements:  dataurisrc: data: URI source element
coreelements:  downloadbuffer: DownloadBuffer
coreelements:  fakesrc: Fake Source
coreelements:  fakesink: Fake Sink
coreelements:  fdsrc: Filedescriptor Source
coreelements:  fdsink: Filedescriptor Sink
coreelements:  filesrc: File Source
coreelements:  funnel: Funnel pipe fitting
coreelements:  identity: Identity
coreelements:  input-selector: Input selector
coreelements:  output-selector: Output selector
coreelements:  queue: Queue
coreelements:  queue2: Queue 2
coreelements:  filesink: File Sink
coreelements:  tee: Tee pipe fitting
coreelements:  typefind: TypeFind
coreelements:  multiqueue: MultiQueue
coreelements:  valve: Valve element
coreelements:  streamiddemux: Streamid Demux
audiotestsrc:  audiotestsrc: Audio test source
audioconvert:  audioconvert: Audio converter
opengl:  glimagesink: GL Sink Bin
opengl:  glimagesinkelement: OpenGL video sink
opengl:  glupload: OpenGL uploader
opengl:  gldownload: OpenGL downloader
opengl:  glcolorconvert: OpenGL color converter
opengl:  glcolorbalance: Video balance
opengl:  glfilterbin: GL Filter Bin
opengl:  glsinkbin: GL Sink Bin
opengl:  glsrcbin: GL Src Bin
opengl:  glfiltercube: OpenGL cube filter
opengl:  gleffects: Gstreamer OpenGL Effects
opengl:  gleffects_identity: Do nothing Effect
opengl:  gleffects_mirror: Mirror Effect
opengl:  gleffects_squeeze: Squeeze Effect
opengl:  gleffects_stretch: Stretch Effect
opengl:  gleffects_tunnel: Light Tunnel Effect
opengl:  gleffects_fisheye: FishEye Effect
opengl:  gleffects_twirl: Twirl Effect
opengl:  gleffects_bulge: Bulge Effect
opengl:  gleffects_square: Square Effect
opengl:  gleffects_heat: Heat Signature Effect
opengl:  gleffects_sepia: Sepia Toning Effect
opengl:  gleffects_xpro: Cross Processing Effect
opengl:  gleffects_lumaxpro: Luma Cross Processing Effect
opengl:  gleffects_xray: Glowing negative effect
opengl:  gleffects_sin: All Grey but Red Effect
opengl:  gleffects_glow: Glow Lighting Effect
opengl:  gleffects_sobel: Sobel edge detection Effect
opengl:  gleffects_blur: Blur with 9x9 separable convolution Effect
opengl:  gleffects_laplacian: Laplacian Convolution Demo Effect
opengl:  glcolorscale: OpenGL color scale
opengl:  glshader: OpenGL fragment shader filter
opengl:  glfilterapp: OpenGL application filter
opengl:  glviewconvert: OpenGL Multiview/3D conversion filter
opengl:  glstereosplit: GLStereoSplit
opengl:  gltestsrc: Video test source
opengl:  gldeinterlace: OpenGL deinterlacing filter
opengl:  glfilterglass: OpenGL glass filter
app:  appsrc: AppSrc
app:  appsink: AppSink
encoding:  encodebin: Encoder Bin
ximagesink:  ximagesink: Video sink
videorate:  videorate: Video rate adjuster
subparse: subparse_typefind: srt, sub, mpsub, mdvd, smi, txt, dks, vtt
subparse:  subparse: Subtitle parser
subparse:  ssaparse: SSA Subtitle Parser
gio:  giosink: GIO sink
gio:  giosrc: GIO source
gio:  giostreamsink: GIO stream sink
gio:  giostreamsrc: GIO stream source
volume:  volume: Volume
tcp:  socketsrc: socket source
tcp:  tcpclientsink: TCP client sink
tcp:  tcpclientsrc: TCP client source
tcp:  tcpserversink: TCP server sink
tcp:  tcpserversrc: TCP server source
tcp:  multifdsink: Multi filedescriptor sink
tcp:  multisocketsink: Multi socket sink
videoscale:  videoscale: Video scaler
rawparse:  unalignedaudioparse: unalignedaudioparse
rawparse:  unalignedvideoparse: unalignedvideoparse
rawparse:  rawaudioparse: rawaudioparse
rawparse:  rawvideoparse: rawvideoparse
playback:  playbin: Player Bin 2
playback:  playbin3: Player Bin 3
playback:  playsink: Player Sink
playback:  subtitleoverlay: Subtitle Overlay
playback:  streamsynchronizer: Stream Synchronizer
playback:  decodebin: Decoder Bin
playback:  decodebin3: Decoder Bin 3
playback:  uridecodebin: URI Decoder
playback:  uridecodebin3: URI Decoder
playback:  urisourcebin: URI reader
playback:  parsebin: Parse Bin
audioresample:  audioresample: Audio resampler
audiorate:  audiorate: Audio rate adjuster
typefindfunctions: video/x-ms-asf: asf, wm, wma, wmv
typefindfunctions: audio/x-musepack: mpc, mpp, mp+
typefindfunctions: audio/x-au: au, snd
typefindfunctions: video/x-msvideo: avi
typefindfunctions: audio/qcelp: qcp
typefindfunctions: video/x-cdxa: dat
typefindfunctions: video/x-vcd: dat
typefindfunctions: audio/x-imelody: imy, ime, imelody
typefindfunctions: audio/midi: mid, midi
typefindfunctions: audio/riff-midi: mid, midi
typefindfunctions: audio/mobile-xmf: mxmf
typefindfunctions: video/x-fli: flc, fli
typefindfunctions: application/x-id3v2: mp3, mp2, mp1, mpga, ogg, flac, tta
typefindfunctions: application/x-id3v1: mp3, mp2, mp1, mpga, ogg, flac, tta
typefindfunctions: application/x-apetag: mp3, ape, mpc, wv
typefindfunctions: audio/x-ttafile: tta
typefindfunctions: audio/x-mod: 669, amf, ams, dbm, digi, dmf, dsm, gdm, far, imf, it, j2b, mdl, med, mod, mt2, mtm, okt, psm, ptm, sam, s3m, stm, stx, ult, umx, xm
typefindfunctions: audio/mpeg: mp3, mp2, mp1, mpga
typefindfunctions: audio/x-ac3: ac3, eac3
typefindfunctions: audio/x-dts: dts
typefindfunctions: audio/x-gsm: gsm
typefindfunctions: video/mpeg-sys: mpe, mpeg, mpg
typefindfunctions: video/mpegts: ts, mts
typefindfunctions: application/ogg: ogg, oga, ogv, ogm, ogx, spx, anx, axa, axv
typefindfunctions: video/mpeg-elementary: mpv, mpeg, mpg
typefindfunctions: video/mpeg4: m4v
typefindfunctions: video/x-h263: h263, 263
typefindfunctions: video/x-h264: h264, x264, 264
typefindfunctions: video/x-h265: h265, x265, 265
typefindfunctions: video/x-nuv: nuv
typefindfunctions: audio/x-m4a: m4a
typefindfunctions: application/x-3gp: 3gp
typefindfunctions: video/quicktime: mov, mp4
typefindfunctions: image/x-quicktime: qif, qtif, qti
typefindfunctions: image/jp2: jp2
typefindfunctions: image/x-jpc: jpc, j2k
typefindfunctions: video/mj2: mj2
typefindfunctions: text/html: htm, html
typefindfunctions: application/vnd.rn-realmedia: ra, ram, rm, rmvb
typefindfunctions: application/x-pn-realaudio: ra, ram, rm, rmvb
typefindfunctions: application/x-shockwave-flash: swf, swfl
typefindfunctions: application/dash+xml: mpd, MPD
typefindfunctions: application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml: no extensions
typefindfunctions: video/x-flv: flv
typefindfunctions: text/plain: txt
typefindfunctions: text/utf-16: txt
typefindfunctions: text/utf-32: txt
typefindfunctions: text/uri-list: ram
typefindfunctions: application/itc: itc
typefindfunctions: application/x-hls: m3u8
typefindfunctions: application/sdp: sdp
typefindfunctions: application/smil: smil
typefindfunctions: application/ttml+xml: ttml+xml
typefindfunctions: application/xml: xml
typefindfunctions: audio/x-wav: wav
typefindfunctions: audio/x-aiff: aiff, aif, aifc
typefindfunctions: audio/x-svx: iff, svx
typefindfunctions: audio/x-paris: paf
typefindfunctions: audio/x-nist: nist
typefindfunctions: audio/x-voc: voc
typefindfunctions: audio/x-sds: sds
typefindfunctions: audio/x-ircam: sf
typefindfunctions: audio/x-w64: w64
typefindfunctions: audio/x-rf64: rf64
typefindfunctions: audio/x-shorten: shn
typefindfunctions: application/x-ape: ape
typefindfunctions: image/jpeg: jpg, jpe, jpeg
typefindfunctions: image/gif: gif
typefindfunctions: image/png: png
typefindfunctions: image/bmp: bmp
typefindfunctions: image/tiff: tif, tiff
typefindfunctions: image/webp: webp
typefindfunctions: image/x-exr: exr
typefindfunctions: image/x-portable-pixmap: pnm, ppm, pgm, pbm
typefindfunctions: video/x-matroska: mkv, mka, mk3d, webm
typefindfunctions: application/mxf: mxf
typefindfunctions: video/x-mve: mve
typefindfunctions: video/x-dv: dv, dif
typefindfunctions: audio/x-amr-nb-sh: amr
typefindfunctions: audio/x-amr-wb-sh: amr
typefindfunctions: audio/iLBC-sh: ilbc
typefindfunctions: audio/x-sbc: sbc
typefindfunctions: audio/x-sid: sid
typefindfunctions: image/x-xcf: xcf
typefindfunctions: video/x-mng: mng
typefindfunctions: image/x-jng: jng
typefindfunctions: image/x-xpixmap: xpm
typefindfunctions: image/x-sun-raster: ras
typefindfunctions: application/x-bzip: bz2
typefindfunctions: application/x-gzip: gz
typefindfunctions: application/zip: zip
typefindfunctions: application/x-compress: Z
typefindfunctions: subtitle/x-kate: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-subtitle-vtt: vtt
typefindfunctions: audio/x-flac: flac
typefindfunctions: audio/x-vorbis: no extensions
typefindfunctions: video/x-theora: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-ogm-video: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-ogm-audio: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-ogm-text: no extensions
typefindfunctions: audio/x-speex: no extensions
typefindfunctions: audio/x-celt: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-ogg-skeleton: no extensions
typefindfunctions: text/x-cmml: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-executable: no extensions
typefindfunctions: audio/aac: aac, adts, adif, loas
typefindfunctions: audio/x-spc: spc
typefindfunctions: audio/x-wavpack: wv, wvp
typefindfunctions: audio/x-wavpack-correction: wvc
typefindfunctions: audio/x-caf: caf
typefindfunctions: application/postscript: ps
typefindfunctions: image/svg+xml: svg
typefindfunctions: application/x-rar: rar
typefindfunctions: application/x-tar: tar
typefindfunctions: application/x-ar: a
typefindfunctions: application/x-ms-dos-executable: dll, exe, ocx, sys, scr, msstyles, cpl
typefindfunctions: video/x-dirac: no extensions
typefindfunctions: multipart/x-mixed-replace: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-mmsh: no extensions
typefindfunctions: video/vivo: viv
typefindfunctions: audio/x-nsf: nsf
typefindfunctions: audio/x-gym: gym
typefindfunctions: audio/x-ay: ay
typefindfunctions: audio/x-gbs: gbs
typefindfunctions: audio/x-vgm: vgm
typefindfunctions: audio/x-sap: sap
typefindfunctions: video/x-ivf: ivf
typefindfunctions: audio/x-kss: kss
typefindfunctions: application/pdf: pdf
typefindfunctions: application/msword: doc
typefindfunctions: image/vnd.adobe.photoshop: psd
typefindfunctions: image/vnd.wap.wbmp: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-yuv4mpeg: no extensions
typefindfunctions: image/x-icon: no extensions
typefindfunctions: image/x-degas: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/octet-stream: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-ssa: ssa, ass
typefindfunctions: video/x-pva: pva
typefindfunctions: audio/x-xi: xi
typefindfunctions: audio/audible: aa, aax
staticelements:  bin: Generic bin
staticelements:  pipeline: Pipeline object

Total count: 25 plugins, 253 features
```

I have removed the cache by running:

```
rm -rf .cache/gstreamer-1
```

Nothing changed.

I have removed completely gstreamer and I have reinstalled it again with the following command (it is longer than need but I have reinstalled some packages that were also remove when gstreamer was removed.)

> **sudo apt install libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio** calibre evince gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-qapt gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3 gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-vaapi gstreamer1.0-x kaccounts-integration kde-runtime kdelibs5-plugins kinfocenter kio-gdrive ksysguard ktorrent kubuntu-desktop kwin kwin-addons kwin-common kwin-x11 libevview3-3 libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-dev libkdewebkit5 libkf5webkit5 libplasma3 libprocessui7 libqgsttools-p1 libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5webkit5 libqtwebkit4 libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libreoffice-kde libreoffice-kde4 libspice-server1 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 liferea oem-config oem-config-kde packagekit packagekit-tools phonon-backend-gstreamer phonon4qt5-backend-gstreamer plasma-desktop plasma-discover plasma-scriptengine-javascript plasma-widgets-addons plasma-workspace pychess python-pyqt5.qtwebkit python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit qemu-kvm qemu-system-x86 qml-module-qtmultimedia qml-module-qtwebkit qt5-assistant qttools5-dev-tools sddm-theme-breeze signon-ui-x11 ubiquity ubiquity-frontend-kde zenity

Which includes the good plugins, where the v4l2sink is contained as you can see [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-v4l2sink.html). No problems came out from the installation but the problem persisted.

I have double-checked that the plugins have been properly installed:

```
sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good is already the newest version (1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 69 not upgraded.
```

I run also the following command

```
locate libgstvideo4linux2.so
```

This library contains the element v4l2sink that I was trying to use as you can see [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-plugin-video4linux2.html). I got

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0
```

I have seen that LD_LIBRARY_PATH did not contain this directory so I added it by running:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0
```

I know this only change the path in the current terminal, so I run again the same commands I listed before in that terminal and it returned the same results.

Comment: By any chance, do you use anaconda? It overrides the paths for gstreamer. You can check if you are using the conda's gstreamer by running `which gst-launch-1.0` or `which gst-inspect-1.0`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I am using anaconda. Both commands returned the anaconda path: ~/anaconda3/bin/gst-launch-1.0    and     ~/anaconda3/bin/gst-inspect-1.0. I would try to change this behaviour by explicitly state the path to the gstreamer of my choice. I will come back with my results.

Comment: @AlperKucukkomurler, your suggestion worked. I have edited also other scripts to make this works, including the v4l2loopback/utils/v4l2loopback-ctl script and the prepare-videochat.sh, both of which has been involved in finding the solution to my final problem. After doing that, I also encountered other problems that where solved by using the help provided in https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/174 and the command v4l2loopback-ctl set-caps "video/x-raw,format=UYVY,width=640,height=480" /dev/video1

Comment: @AlperKucukkomurler thank you, I was wondering what happened for 3 hours now...