# Gstreamer does not work in Ubuntu 22.10: pipeline no element problem

Tags: ubuntu, gstreamer

I just installed the gstreamer tools using:

```
sudo apt install libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
```

and it installed succesfully without any errors. Then:
[all tools appeared in my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSe5u.png)

but if I try to launch simple code, like

```
gst-launch-1.0 fakesrc
```

it gives the error in output without any comprehensive logs:

```
ERROR: pipeline could not be constructed: no element "fakesrc".
```

so, is it not  possible to install gstreamer properly in Ubuntu 22.10 or there should be any another installation command?

I tryed [gstreamer:No such element or plugin 'videotestsrc'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25378985/gstreamerno-such-element-or-plugin-videotestsrc) but without any success

Answer (score 0):

It could be one of many things.

Run `gst-inspect-1.0` and see what all elements the tool detects.

If it did not detect any of the elements (you have installed good, bad, ugly plugins so it should be a lot of elements) then probably check your GST_PLUGINS_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LIBRARY_PATH. If it is set to something custom, then it might not be able to detect.

Delete the file in `$HOME/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/*` It might have some cached entries for plugins and may be is not able to detect it.